# Volley JSON onResponse calling separate function

Tags: android, json, overriding, response, android-volley

I am pretty new to Java and Android programming so please excuse some questions :) I am having trouble with volley and the onResponse function. Here is my source code:

```
     static void makeJsonObjReq(JSONObject test) {

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
            Const.URL_JSON_OBJECT, test,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    //separateResponse(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                }
            })};
```

This is working for me. This is how I am calling this type of request:

```
 JsonRequestActivity.makeJsonObjReq(test);
```

The problem I have is, that I have to do really many requests which have different response behaviors.

Question:

How can I rewrite or even create a new onResponse behavior for this class? That I can call `JsonRequestActivity.makeJsonObjReq(test);` this and just have to rewrite the onResponse part pretty easy, like this:

```
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    do sth here...
                }
```

and for a request within an other function:
`JsonRequestActivity.makeJsonObjReq(differentobject);`

```
                    @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    if(...)
                        do other things here
                }
```

Is this possible? Or do I have to create a lots of function of the JsonRequestActivity.makeJsonObjReq for a different onRepsonse behavior?

I even got one more question: Is it a leak of performance calling functions out of the `JsonRequestActivity.makeJsonObjReq` as I tried with the `//separateResponse(response);`? Because of how volley is working (threads and more)?

SOURCE: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/